# Query nested JSON structure to find the object having the minimum value in a child array

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have the following JSON:

```
{
  "travelClasses": [
    {
      "fares": [
        {
          "referenceId": "a",
          "fare": {
            "tax": 48.99,
            "totalFare": 519.99,
            "currency": {
              "code": "USD",
              "exchangeRate": 1
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "availableSeats": 9,
      "type": "Pro",
      "code": "B",
      "name": "UX"
    },
    {
      "fares": [
        {
          "referenceId": "b",
          "fare": {
            "tax": 98.99,
            "totalFare": 119.99,
            "currency": {
              "code": "USD",
              "exchangeRate": 1
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "availableSeats": 9,
      "type": "Pro",
      "code": "C",
      "name": "UC"
    },
    {
      "fares": [
        {
          "referenceId": "c",
          "fare": {
            "tax": 48.99,
            "totalFare": 819.99,
            "currency": {
              "code": "USD",
              "exchangeRate": 1
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "availableSeats": 9,
      "type": "Eco",
      "code": "X",
      "name": "US"
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to query this JSON then I would like to retrieve the object which has the minimum `totalFare`. In my sample, the second node has the minimum `totalFare`, so I need to retrieve following JSON's object with something like `.ToObject<TravelClass>()`.

```
{
  "fares": [
    {
      "referenceId": "b",
      "fare": {
        "tax": 98.99,
        "totalFare": 119.99,
        "currency": {
          "code": "USD",
          "exchangeRate": 1
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "availableSeats": 9,
  "type": "Pro",
  "code": "C",
  "name": "UC"
}
```

I checked the [Newtonsoft documentation](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SelectToken.htm) about querying a `JObject` but I couldn't solve that.

Finally here is the C# code that I tried:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            JObject o = JObject.Parse(@"{
              'travelClasses': [
                {
                  'fares': [
                    {
                      'referenceId': 'a',
                      'fare': {
                        'tax': 48.99,
                        'totalFare': 519.99,
                        'currency': {
                          'code': 'USD',
                          'exchangeRate': 1
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ],
                  'availableSeats': 9,
                  'type': 'Pro',
                  'code': 'B',
                  'name': 'UX'
                },
                {
                  'fares': [
                    {
                      'referenceId': 'b',
                      'fare': {
                        'tax': 98.99,
                        'totalFare': 119.99,
                        'currency': {
                          'code': 'USD',
                          'exchangeRate': 1
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ],
                  'availableSeats': 9,
                  'type': 'Pro',
                  'code': 'C',
                  'name': 'UC'
                },
                {
                  'fares': [
                    {
                      'referenceId': 'c',
                      'fare': {
                        'tax': 48.99,
                        'totalFare': 819.99,
                        'currency': {
                          'code': 'USD',
                          'exchangeRate': 1
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ],
                  'availableSeats': 9,
                  'type': 'Eco',
                  'code': 'X',
                  'name': 'US'
                }
              ]
            }");

            var minFareTravelClassObject = o["travelClasses"]
                .Select(m => m.SelectToken("fares")
                .OrderByDescending(x => x["totalFare"]))
                .FirstOrDefault();     
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}

public partial class TravelClass
{
    [JsonProperty("fares")]
    public List<FareElement> Fares { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("availableSeats")]
    public int AvailableSeats { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("code")]
    public string Code { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public partial class FareElement
{
    [JsonProperty("referenceId")]
    public string ReferenceId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("fare")]
    public FareFare Fare { get; set; }
}

public partial class FareFare
{
    [JsonProperty("tax")]
    public decimal Tax { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("totalFare")]
    public decimal TotalFare { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("currency")]
    public Currency Currency { get; set; }
}

public partial class Currency
{
    [JsonProperty("code")]
    public string Code { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("exchangeRate")]
    public decimal ExchangeRate { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have classes defined to receive the data, I would suggest deserializing to those and skipping the `JObject`.  You only need one more class to represent the root level:

```
public class RootObject
{
    [JsonProperty("travelClasses")]
    public List<TravelClass> TravelClasses { get; set; }
}
```

You can deserialize like this:

```
var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```

From there you can use a LINQ query to find the `TravelClass` with the lowest `TotalFare`:

```
var bestTravelClass = root.TravelClasses
    .SelectMany(tc => tc.Fares, (tc, f) => new { TravelClass = tc, f.Fare.TotalFare })
    .OrderBy(a => a.TotalFare)
    .Select(a => a.TravelClass)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/8WoW5J